# How to show Time Duration of all .mp3 files in a Playlist in jPlayer.

Tags: javascript, html, jplayer, playlist

I want to show time duration of all .mp3 files in jPlayer. My playlist should looks like-[image]

I have used following script-

```
$j(document).ready(function(){



new jPlayerPlaylist({
            jPlayer: "#jquery_jplayer_1",
            cssSelectorAncestor: "#jp_container_1"
        }, 

        [
            <?php $i=0; ?>
            <?php foreach ($record as $rec) : ?>
            {
                title:"<?php echo str_pad(++$i,2,"0",STR_PAD_LEFT); ?> &nbsp; &nbsp; <?php echo $rec['title']; ?>",
                mp3: "<?php echo $rec['content']; ?>"

            },
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        ], 

        {
        solution: 'html, flash',
        swfPath: "<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl('js').'custom/jQuery.jPlayer.2.4.0/'; ?>",
        supplied: "oga, mp3",
        wmode: "window",
        smoothPlayBar: true,
        keyEnabled: true,
        preload: "auto",
        });

    });
```

I am getting all .mp3 files in PHP loop.

Now how can I get duration of each .mp3 file as shown in above image.

Please help me and Thanks in advance.